# Expandable Datasheet View

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

Is there a way to have a nested crosstab displayed on a form?

I have a data hierarchy where the top-level crosstab defines the category and a header descriptor.  The sub-level crosstab will take the header descriptor and represent the data.

Top-Level:
Category, F1, F2, F3

Sub-Level:
Value, F1-val, F2-val, F3-val

F1 - F3 are not static enough to hard-code and may expand/contract overtime but `Value` will always be there, assuming the end user uses them and assigns a value associated with F1 - F3.

Would be alot easier if the DataSheet View that is present in the Table view, which allows for dynamic expansion/contraction of Fields on the fly.

I know i wont be able to update the associated Table(s) through the Cross-Tab and so then leads to another problem.

If this is possible, how would i iterate through said DataSheet view to extract the values for updating the appropriate table(s).

Comment: I wrote a bit about that both in SO and here: http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Crosstabs,_forms_and_updating

Comment: nice....ill start working on that.  Looks like its what i am looking for but will have to implement first ;)

Comment: Ran into a problem with editing information produced by the Xtab, so now im going to load the Xtab into a Listbox and allow the user to edit the information via double-clicking the line to edit ;)  GOing to start working on the implementation of the concept and see how it works ;)